# Display inline arrays

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

```js
 var html3 = '<div class="row" id="parent-autor"> <p id="auth-del"><i class="fa fa-minus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></p> <div class="col-md-4"> <div class="form-group"> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="altautorprenume[]"  placeholder="Prename"> </div> </div> <div class="col-md-4"> <div class="form-group"> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="altautornume[]" placeholder="Name"> </div> </div><div class="col-md-4"> <div class="form-group"> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="institutie[]" id="institutie" placeholder="Institutions"> </div> </div></div>';


        $("#add_aut").click(function(e){
            $('#auth-rows').append(html3);
        });

        $('#auth-rows').on('click', '#auth-del', function(E){
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
        });
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="add-plus"></div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <h5>Add more persons </h5>
    <span class="btn btn-primary" id="add_aut" style="">Click here to add</span>
  </div>
</div>

 <div id="auth-rows"></div>
```

i have an formular which user can add more clients to invite at party when user click on Add a new row with 3 fields appear he can add how many he want,
these values dynamically i want to show on email, for example:

User fill all fields and add 3 more users where they have Name PreName Instituional,look what i did:

```
$personName= $_POST['personname'];
$personPrename= $_POST['personprename'];
$institution= $_POST['institution'];
$otherPersonName=" "; 
$otherPersonPreName="";
$otherPersonInstitution= "";

 foreach($personName as $product) {
  $otherPersonPreName.= "$product";
}

foreach($personPrename as $products) {
  $altiautoriNume .= "$products";
}

foreach($institution as $productss) {
  $otherPersonInstitution.= "$productss";
} 
EXAMPLE:
And in email content i want to display like this:
<hr>
John(first name of person added) Doe(first Prename of person added) Microsoft(first Institution of person added)
<hr>
Mike(second name of person added) Stuart(second Prename of person added)  Facebook(second Institution of person added)
<hr>
```

I know i did something wrong.
I put even html to see truly what i want to do, i want to group Name Prename Institution per line

Comment: var_dump each var and edit q with output. At the mo, in my head, you shouldn't be looping things that seem individual

Comment: You should provide examples of your input and desired output.

Comment: Ok i will add 1 second, EDIT: Done, you have example below the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [array-map](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) with `null` as first parameter to group the array and then use [`implode`](https://www.php.net/implode) to concat the strings.

Consider the following:

```
$arr = array_map(null, $personName, $personPrename, $institution);
foreach($arr as $e)
    echo implode(" ", $e) . PHP_EOL;
```

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/7tnsC)